# Print plain text of help file to console

Tags: r

How can I print the plain-text version of an R help file to the console as a string?  I thought I could could print with:

```
help(optim,help_type="text")
```

But this pops up a help dialog in both R shell and RStudio

When I do

```
a <- help(optim,help_type="text")
cat(a)
```

I get

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/help/optim
```

I examined this folder and it appears that the help files themselves are buried in the binaries.  Is there anyway to access the plain text (or HTML versions) so I can work with the text?